# Understanding Python Queues and Setting threads to run as a Daemon thread

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Lets say I have the below code:

```
import Queue
import threading
import time

def basic_worker(queue, thread_name):
    while True:
       if queue.empty(): break

       print "Starting %s" % (threading.currentThread().getName()) + "\n"
       item = queue.get()
       ##do_work on item which might take 10-15 minutes to complete
       queue.task_done()

       print "Ending %s" % (threading.currentThread().getName()) + "\n"


def basic(queue):
# http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html

    for i in range(10):
       t = threading.Thread(target=basic_worker,args=(queue,tName,))
       t.daemon = True
       t.start()
    queue.join()       # block until all tasks are done
    print 'got here' + '\n'

queue = Queue.Queue()

for item in range(4):
     queue.put(item)



basic(queue)


print "End of program"
```

My question is, if I set `t.daemon = True` will it exit the code killing the threads that are taking 10-15 minutes to do some work on the `item` from the queue? Because from what I have read it says that the program will exit if there are any daemonic threads alive. My understanding is that the threads working on the item taking a long time will also exit incompletely. If I don't set `t.daemon = True` my program hangs forever and doesn't exit when there are no items in the queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the programm hangs forever if `t.daemon = False`, is that the following code block ...

```
if queue.empty(): break
```

... leads to a race-condition.

Imagine there is only one item left in the queue and two threads evaluate the condition above nearly simultaneously. The condition evaluates to `False` for both threads ... so they don't `break`.
The faster thread gets the last item, while the slower hangs forever in the statement `item = queue.get()`.

Respecting the fact that daemon mode is `False` the program waits for all threads to be finished. That never happens.

From my point of view, the code you provided (with `t.daemon = True`), works fine.

May the following sentence confuses you:

> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.

... but consider: If you start all threads from the main thread with `t.daemon = True`, the only non-daemon thread is the main thread itself. So the program exists when the main thread is finished.
... and that does not happen until the queue is empty, because of the `queue.join()` statement. So you long running computations inside the child threads will not be interrupted.

There is no need to check the queue.empty(), when using daemon threads and queue.join().

This should be enough:

```
#!/bin/python
import Queue
import threading
import time

def basic_worker(queue, thread_name):
    print "Starting %s" % (threading.currentThread().getName()) + "\n"
    while True:
       item = queue.get()
       ##do_work on item which might take 10-15 minutes to complete
       time.sleep(5) # to simulate work
       queue.task_done()

def basic(queue):
# http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html

    for i in range(10):
       print 'enqueuing', i
       t = threading.Thread(target=basic_worker, args=(queue, i))
       t.daemon = True
       t.start()
    queue.join()       # block until all tasks are done
    print 'got here' + '\n'

queue = Queue.Queue()

for item in range(4):
     queue.put(item)

basic(queue)


print "End of program"
```

Comment: Thank you! The python docs are confusing and without adequate information about this! After posting the question I went back and looked hard at my code again and did a sleep of 2 minutes to simulate some sort of work (exactly like you mentioned) and realized that those threads don't get interrupted. The race condition in my queue.empty() check doesn't happen always. If i run this code from a shell script that calls the python script inside an infinite while loop, after 4-5 runs I see the python process hanging. And logging the queue size etc confirmed what you said! So thanks!